# Django keep statistics up to date

Tags: database, django

I have a Django model and I want to show some statistics about it. E.g. I have a field like color in it and I want to display how many of the entries have their color set to "red", "green" etc.

Since I have a lot of rows in the table and several colors I do not want to calculate the sum of each statistic on every read.

Therefore I tried to come up with a second table holding the calculated sum. But now I have to keep this information in sync with the original table. E.g. whenever an entry is added, deleted or modifed, I have to update the statistic table.

How would I do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending of your row count but `select count(id) ... GROUP BY` is generally fast.

Otherwise, [Django signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/) is a very interesting concept for this purpose. You can 'listen' to some events like model saved/deleted... or use your custom signals.

In your case, you want to listen to model `post_save` and `post_delete` signals.

heres an example :

```
from django.db.models import signals
import models

def itemSaved(sender, **kwargs):
    obj = kwargs['instance']
    colorMod =  models.Color.get(name = obj.color)
    colorMod.count = colorMod.count + 1
    colorMod.save()

# listen to post_save event for model MyModel
signals.post_save.connect(itemSaved, sender=models.MyModel)
```

Place this code inside a models.py

Hope this helps.

**EDIT** : Also see this [new F operator technique example](http://www.djangofoo.com/298/incrementdecrement-field-value) for a single sql operation

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, I used your approach using custom post save and delete handler. I am just a bit nervous about database consistency. Therefore I do not update any count value with +1 but rather recount on every change. I also would otherwise have to decrement and increment during an update (e.g. on pre_save, decrement and on post_save increment).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django Signals for this. Specifically, look at `post_save` and `post_delete`. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/